# Some doubts about .NET wGrid.Column()?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am very new in **C#** and **.NET** (I came from Java) and I have some doubt about how the following view work:

```
@model DataModel.MaliciousCode.SearchMalicious
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/MasterPageMobile.cshtml";

    WebGrid wGrid = new WebGrid(null, rowsPerPage: Model.PageSize, defaultSort: "Published", canPage: false);
    wGrid.Bind(Model.MaliciousCode, rowCount: Model.TotalRows, autoSortAndPage: false);

}

<h2>Index Andrea</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Malicious", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "MyForm" }))
{

    <div class="ui-field-contain">
        <label for="Filter_Title">Title:</label>
        <input type ="text" data-mini="true" data-clear-btn="true" id="Filter_Title" name="Filter.Title"  value="@Model.Filter.Title"   />
    </div>   

    <div data-role="controlgrup" data-type="horizontal" data-mini="true">
        <input type="reset" data-inline="true" data-mini="true" value="Reset" />
        <input type="submit" data-inline="true" data-mini="true" value="Seach" data-icon="search" />
    </div>
}


pageSize : @Model.PageSize

@if (Model.TotalRows == 0)
{
    <h3>Non è stata trovata nessuna vulnerabilità. Modificare i filtri di ricerca.</h3>
}
else
{


    <div style="margin-top: 20px;">
        <p>TABELLA</p>
        @wGrid.GetHtml(
            fillEmptyRows: false,
            tableStyle: "MyTable ui-responsive",
            headerStyle: "ui-bar-b",
            footerStyle: "ui-bar-b",
            rowStyle: "ui-bar-a",
            alternatingRowStyle: "ui-bar-c",
            htmlAttributes: new { data_role = "table", id = "MyWebGrid", data_mode = "reflow" },
            columns: new[]{

                    wGrid.Column ("Title", "Title", canSort : true),
                    wGrid.Column ("Discovered", "Discovered",  format: p=>p.Discovered.ToShortDateString() ,canSort : true), 

            })

        @{Html.RenderPartial("Paging", Model);}
    </div>
}
```

As you can see in this view I have a table that show the objects that are inside a collection (that I think is inside my model object, is it trye?), this one:

```
    @wGrid.GetHtml(
        fillEmptyRows: false,
        tableStyle: "MyTable ui-responsive",
        headerStyle: "ui-bar-b",
        footerStyle: "ui-bar-b",
        rowStyle: "ui-bar-a",
        alternatingRowStyle: "ui-bar-c",
        htmlAttributes: new { data_role = "table", id = "MyWebGrid", data_mode = "reflow" },
        columns: new[]{

                wGrid.Column ("Title", "Title", canSort : true),
                wGrid.Column ("Discovered", "Discovered",  format: p=>p.Discovered.ToShortDateString() ,canSort : true), 

        })
```

My doubts are:

1. In this line what exactly represent the 2 strings: **"Title"** and **"Title"** passed as parameters of the **wGrid.Coumn()** method?

   wGrid.Column ("Title", "Title", canSort : true),
2. In the second column I have one more parameter :

   wGrid.Column ("Discovered", "Discovered",  format: p=>p.Discovered.ToShortDateString() ,canSort : true),

What exactly represent **format: p=>p.Discovered.ToShortDateString()** and what is the p object?

Tnx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. I hope you are using Visual Studio. It would show you the description of the column method with its parameters by pressing *Ctr + Space* after

   ```
   webGrid.Column(
   ```

   But you find the  description as well in the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.webgrid.column%28v=vs.111%29.aspx). As you can see, the first parameter is the column name, the second parameter is the column header.
2. That is a [Lamda Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx). In this context, p is an object of whatever "Row" the WebGrid was bound to.